# Sum consecutive rows' values between 2 conditions using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sum consecutive rows values between 2 conditions.
Here is my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes"],'B':["no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes"],'C':[2,5,1,4,6,13,7,8,3,9,1]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

In fact, when `A="yes"` and `B="no"`, I would like to start adding rows values until `A="no"` and `B="yes"`.
I would like to get the following result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","yes"],'B':["no","no"],'C':[12,18]},index=[0, 6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask twice to get your desired outcome.

In the first mask, you filter the rows whose sum you'll need to find. In the second, you find the sum.

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['A']=='yes')&(x['B']=='no') else (-1 if (x['A']=='no')&(x['B']=='yes') else 0), axis=1).cumsum().astype(bool)
mask2 = df[mask].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['A']=='yes') & (x['B']=='no') else 0, axis=1)
out = df[mask][mask2.astype(bool)]
out['C'] = df[mask].groupby(mask2.cumsum())['C'].sum().to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C
0  yes  no  12
6  yes  no  18
```